# How much faster (or slower) would it be for a new probe to reach Pluto?

Tags: new-horizons, pluto, time

New Horizions just reached Pluto after almost a decade in space. That means it was launched with technology that is well over a decade old (when you factor in planning and construction time).

If we had a new probe with modern technology on the launch pad today, how long would it take to get to Pluto? Would it be significantly faster? Would it depend heavily on the alignment of the planets (ie the Jupiter slingshot maneuver)?

Comment: It actually would be slower, for a number of reasons. Pluto is further out than it was previously, and there won't be as good of a slingshot (I believe) as there was for New Horizons.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Do you know approximately how much further out it is?

Comment: I would think if it had ion thrusters that could still make a big difference.

Comment: @briligg I thought ion thrusters were really efficient but really slow?

Comment: Ion thrusters could work actually, it helps if you will be in transit for a long time. I'm toying with the idea of making an ion powered craft simulator, will have to play with it some...

Comment: http://www.space.com/18566-pluto-distance.html

Comment: Efficiency *is* speed at these distances.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Modern technology doesn't change the major constraints of rocket propulsion significantly.

In the absence of a gravity assist, the most fuel-efficient route from Earth to Pluto is approximately a 45-year journey. Bringing that down to 9 years already represents a large investment in propulsion fuel; [New Horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons) set the record for the highest launch speed of a human-made object from Earth (~16 km/s); the Jupiter flyby increased its speed by another ~4 km/s.

If NH had an ion thruster capability similar to that of the [Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)) spacecraft, with enough fuel for an additional 4km/s of maneuvering, it could have managed roughly the same travel time without the Jupiter assist, or, with both the ion drive and the gravity assist, managed more like a 7-8 year trip.

That kind of capability would come at the cost of something else; NH's very high launch speed was only possible because the spacecraft was so small (about half a ton), and the fuel needed for such an ion thruster would be about a third the mass of the craft. Either a much larger launcher would be needed, or the science package on the probe would have to be much reduced.

Answer (score 11):

For a launch to Pluto, a Jupiter gravitational slingshot opportunity occurs once every 12 years or so (one Jupiter orbit + 12/248, to account for Pluto's movement in those 12 years). The next one is ~2-3 years away.

Then there's the rocket. You want the fastest launch possible. The Atlas V 551 used by New Horizons can put 18 tons into LEO. As a first approximation, more weight to LEO = faster launch of a New Horizons-class probe on its way to Pluto. So going through [this comparison list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_launch_systems), the Proton M does a little better at 21 tons, but the real improvements are still in development, notably the SpaceX Falcon Heavy (53 tons) and the SLS Block II (130 tons).

Those rockets also give the freedom to use an ion engine, and to design better upper stages than the Centaur and STAR-48. I'll leave the number crunching on those to others.

Comment: Why only one rocket to LEO, though?  Launch one science package, one (or several) propulsion units, mate them in orbit.

Comment: That adds a huge amount of complexity and cost to the mission.

Comment: And I think it's understating it to say "huge amount of complexity". More like "HUUUUUUUGE amount of complexity".

Comment: @Russell Borogove: I don't see how.  Automated docking is pretty bog standard stuff these days, with the ISS.  Lots less complex than building a new large launch vehicle that'd only be used for a few missions.

Comment: Docking itself is not a huge challenge. The logistics to enable docking add a huge amount of complexity to the probe: suddenly the probe and everything that docks to it need independent power and attitude control systems (can't dock to a tumbling object) and the active side of docking needs its own propulsion system.  After docking that redundant power/attitude control becomes dead weight that you're dragging out to Pluto.  Also, everything has to work flawlessly during and after years of travel in space, which is why they were trying to get rid of complexity (scan platform) originally.

Comment: Maybe "huge" is overstating it, but for such a small probe, the docking hardware, extra power source, and attitude control is going to be a large part of the mass budget. The cost of the launch itself is not insignificant, either. If you wanted a 1 ton Pluto flyby probe, you'd launch on a single Delta Heavy (~28 ton to LEO) instead of on two Atlases.

Comment: Interesting thread... But following the logic, we might imagine a modular, assemble-in-space craft where the docking and steering components _detach_ (perhaps for reuse!) after assembly. In that way, we could assemble an arbitrarily large robotic craft that consists _only_ of components needed for the voyage. Even the booster stage for trans-Pluto could be multi-stage; large chemical booster to get it going (then ditch it), smaller ion-engine for long-term burn. Finally, throw out a light-sail spinnaker - you'd be at Pluto in no time!

Comment: @OwenBoyle Yeah, we might imagine that. But we're not quite there yet - especially considering the reuse. To allow reasonable reuse, you'd have to boost the craft to a high enough orbit that it would actually stay there. You'd need a way to reliably and accurately track it. You'd still need a way to actually join to the hardware to reuse it. Every single part adds mass and complexity - space travel is complex enough already. Maybe this will diminish as we figure out better ways to boost the payload to orbit, but that's going to take a while. We're not quite there yet.

Comment: @1337joe: But at its simplest, docking doesn't add any complexity to the probe.  Consider a vehicle in two parts: the probe (with ion engines &c) and an Earth-departure chemical booster.  The booster just needs to mate with some pins/sockets on the probe, run until burnout, then back off.  At most trivial extra mass on the probe, and a few maneuvering engines on the booster.

Comment: then you have to hope the backoff goes perfectly; the slightest asymmetrical thrust and those pins are jammed. Also, you'd need a manned mission to assemble the craft in orbit.

Answer (score 7):

Hobbes and Russell Borogove gave good answers. I'd like to add another factor: distance from the sun. Pluto's perihelion is 29.64 AU. Aphelion is 49.12 AU. Last perihelion was in 1989. Pluto's orbital period is about 246 years. So next perihelion is in the year 2,235. During our lifetimes Pluto is only going to get more distant.